# SQL Server select resultset values as a comma-separated string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query in a stored procedure.

```
set @result1='EmpId,EmpName,Phone,City'

set @result2='select '+ @result1+ ' from [emptable]'+' where EmpId=1 and
EmpjoinDate= ''May-2014'''

exec(@result2)
```

The query returns

```
EmpId | EmpName | Phone  | City
----------------------------------   
  1   | John    | 832942 | NewYork
```

Now how to add query so that stored procedure returns single column result

```
| EmpInfo .........................|
------------------------------------    
1,John,832942,NewYork
```

Please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
set @result1='CONCAT(EmpId,',',EmpName,',',Phone,',',City)'

set @result2='select '+ @result1+ ' as EmpInfo from [emptable]'+' where EmpId=1 and
EmpjoinDate= ''May-2014'''

exec(@result2)
```

Comment: This will produce a string like '1John832942NewYork' without commas

Answer (score 0):

If I get you clearly then this is who you want. 
You have to concatenate the fields with the commas

```
set @result1='EmpId+'',''+EmpName''+'',''+''Phone''+'',''+''City'

set @result2='select '+@result1+' as EmpInfo from [emptable]'+' where EmpId=1 and
EmpjoinDate= ''May-2014'''

exec(@result2)
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply. But the '@result1' fetches the column names dynamically at run time and the no of columns may increase or decrease so I can not define '@result1'.

Comment: Ok I now see what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the string in the @result1 variable:

```
set @result1='EmpId+'',''+EmpName+'',''+Phone+'',''+City'
```

In Management Studio, you can also go to the Query Menu and select "Results To" -> "Results to Text" if that is enough for you.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply. But the column names in '@result1' I fetch from cufd table using some query and they are not fixed.

Comment: OK but what is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is after receiving `@result1` you replace data as you wish:

```
set @result1='EmpId,EmpName,Phone,City'


SET  @result1  = REPLACE (@result1, ',', ' + '','' + ')

--SET  @result1  = 'CONCAT ( ' + REPLACE (@result1, ',', ' , '','' , ') + ')'   -- OR THIS IF you have INT inside this columns


set @result2='select '+ @result1+ ' from [emptable]'+' where EmpId=1 and
EmpjoinDate= ''May-2014'''

exec(@result2)
```

With `CONCAT` function looks better, if you have Server 2012. If not you will need `CAST` INT values into String

Comment: Hi, I tried the above query but it is giving error                 Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Using `For XML` and `STUFF` re-write the query as:

```
declare @result1 varchar(max), 
        @result2 varchar(max) 
--Modify all input columns using Cast function to cast int datatype columns 
--to varchar .Also this way you can add as many columns from table 'emptable'
--as you want

set @result1=''','' + cast(EmpId as varchar(20)) + '','' + EmpName + '','' 
    + cast(Phone as varchar(20)) + '','' + City'

set @result2='select STUFF((SELECT '+ @result1+ '  from [emptable] 
    '+' where EmpId=1 FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, '''') as  EmpInfo'

exec(@result2)
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/QEMBQJ16654) here